# Swipe to wake when screen is off

Tags: lock-screens

I would like my new Android (5.0, Galaxy S5) to handle screen locking the way my old Android did (4.something, Galaxy Express).

The old one was set to pattern lock, but after the screen turned off, within 10 minutes I could unlock it with only a swipe. The new one is similar, but during the 10 minute interval, it doesn't require even a swipe--I just push the home button and it's immediately unlocked.

This is a problem because I keep pushing the button accidentally as I put it in my pocket, and the inside of my pocket touches the screen and does random things.

How can I make it require just a swipe, but not the pattern lock, during that time interval after the screen turns off?